# How to show a TaskDialog outside of Windows Form in C#? (comctl v6 is not loaded)

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-api-code-pack, comctl32, taskdialog

I love TaskDialogs and quite often use them, but I have trouble invoking them outside of Windows Form class.
In a Winforms class, they can be invoked easy like this:

```
new Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs.TaskDialog().Show();
```

So to show a general error message if any exception is thrown while running my application, I wrote the same line into static `Program.Main()`:

```
try
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    // TODO: Show error message here
    new Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs.TaskDialog().Show();
}
```

But when this dialog should be shown, I get a `NotSupportedException` at `.Show()`:

> TaskDialog feature needs to load version 6 of comctl32.dll but a different version is current loaded in memory.

`app.manifest` defining the `assemblyIdentity` version to 6.0 is included to project file.

I did some research and found out the TaskDialog could require an `ApplicationContext`, but I don't know how to pass a non-`Windows.Form` object to it.

How can I workaround this issue?
Thanks for any suggestions!

---

(Regarding frequent issues with TaskDialog, I tested this on different NuGet versions of `WindowsAPICodePack` with same result. For best reproduce: `Install-Package WindowsAPICodePack-Core` and `Shell`. Regards)

Comment: You need a manifest that specifies the use of v6 of the common controls. Visual Studio should embed this by default; check your project settings to see what is going wrong.

Comment: @CodyGray In fact, I had already done so, but after restarting IDE it worked now. Thank you!